# Conditional formatting of text containing with openpyxl on entire file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, conditional-formatting

I have searched the entire net and i cant find anything related to this half of the codes i find dont work the other half gives error no one seems to have done this i would use excelwriter but i need to append files into existing excel. Someone please give a proper code format along with imports. I tried reading the documentation but i cant understand anything

I need an entire sheet in a file conditional formatted with red background on every cell that contains "-->" this character in it it could be 'gghhj-->ghhf' and it should get highlighted

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` & `lambda` functions to get your job done.

I assumed that your *existing Excel file* as `excel_file` & and the *sheet* as `sheet`.

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = "excel_file.xlsx"
sheet = "Sheet1"

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')

for file in file_list:
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    df = df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: red' if '-->' in str(x) else '')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False, header=False)
    
writer.save()
```

Comment: This did not work... none of the cells were highlighted

Comment: previous code is updated, try again